# Issue on removing YouTube logo on embedded YouTube video

Tags: html, video, iframe, youtube, embed

I'm embedding a video on my website but I don't want it to have the YouTube logo and the controls. I searched on Google (date was June 2013) and it said that I just need to put "modestbranding=1&controls=0" on the src. The controls doesn't show up, but the YT logo is still there.

Here's my code:

```
<iframe width="471" height="280" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YOUTUBE_ID?modestbranding=1&controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I was wondering if it's still possible to remove the logo. Before, I'm using the `<object>` with `<param name="PARAMETER" value="VALUE">` but I found out that YouTube `<object>` embeds were deprecated as of January 27, 2015. It told me to migrate my applications to use `<iframe>` embeds, which can intelligently use whichever embedded player – HTML (`<video>`) or Flash (`<object>`).

Hope someone can help :) Thank you!

Comment: Seems that Youtube already prevented this function. Thanks for the edit :)